# Cypress intercept call return body as object

Tags: cypress

I have the follwing code

```
cy.intercept({
    method: "GET",
    url: `**/features`
}).as("getFeatures");
cy.wait('@getFeatures').then(({response}) => {
    if(response?.statusCode ===200){
        expect(response.body.features).to.exist;
        expect(response.body.features).to.contain('feature01');
        // hier I would like to return the response.body oder response.body.features as an object to interact with the ui based on its value (wether the feature is activated or not)
    }
})
```

Saving the body into a file is not an option because the tests will run in paralel and different tests may access invalid values of feature endpoint

EDIT: because I need this method more than once. I want to return the value of Body as an object the solution I am looking for is like

function visitUrl() : Object {

//intercept
return body
}

Answer (score 3):

You can use `alias` and save the response body and use it later on.

```js
cy.intercept({
  method: 'GET',
  url: `**/features`,
}).as('getFeatures')
cy.wait('@getFeatures').then(({response}) => {
  if (response?.statusCode === 200) {
    expect(response.body.features).to.exist
    expect(response.body.features).to.contain('feature01')
    cy.wrap(response.body.features).as('responseBodyFeatures')
  }
})

cy.get('@responseBodyFeatures').then((features) => {
  cy.log(features) //logs the features section from response body
})
```

Comment: I do not want to log the features. I want to return the value as described in the post (updated version)

Comment: Logging was just a placeholder code. You can access the `response.body.features` and do whatever you like. How do you intent to use `response.body.features` in your test?

Comment: I want to evaluate it in my tests. the value of features are requested once the page has been visited. upon the values of feature, different actions will be available

Comment: You can access the features values inside `cy.get('@responseBodyFeatures').then((features)` like `features.value1` or `features.value2`.